# Drawing contour / border precisely around view and subviews

Tags: swift, user-interface

I am trying to create a contour of a custom UIView, however when I do this it does not go precisely around the subviews, instead it goes around the entire view. See image below:

[image]

Is there a way I can get it to go around the subviews exactly? Here's how I'm drawing the contour:

```
    self.clipsToBounds = true  
    self.layer.borderWidth = 1
    self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
```

Comment: Your requirement is not clear to me can you explain in more detail. So that i can help you better

Comment: I'd like the black line not to leave any of the white space. It should go around the blue views, which are all subviews of self.

Comment: make clear background for all subviews

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clipping borders to subviews](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278472/clipping-borders-to-subviews)